React/MUI Form validation active after clearing controlled values
I have a React (MUI) form like the following.
import React, { Component, TextField, Button } from 'react'

class MyForm extends Component {
  initialState = { name: '' }

  state = this.initialState

  handleSave = () => {
    // submit values via axios, and reset form

    this.setState(() => this.initialState)
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <form>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          <TextField 
            required
            placeholder="Enter name"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={this.handleNameChange}
          />
        </div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary"
           onClick={this.handleSave}>Save</Button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default MyForm

The problem is when I clear the (controlled) Form values, the validation of the Form activates and alerts the User that the Name field is empty ("Please Fill In This Field").  I want to clear the validation flags when I clear the Form values.
How can this be done?  I'd rather not use a 3rd party Form component, if possible
